# Does Windos IoT support I2C "Repeated-Start Condition" on Raspberry Pi Model 2B

Tags: raspberry-pi2, i2c, windowsiot

I was looking into purchasing a "MLX90614 Non-Contact Sensors" for temperature readings that uses I2C. However it says to make sure that your device supports a non standard I2C "repeated-start." I am currently using Windows IoT 10, raspberry pi 2 Model B. Does anyone know if "Repeated Start" is supported by the Raspberry pi on Windows IoT 10?

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible with the I2cDevice.WriteRead method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.devices.i2c.i2cdevice.writeread